# On touch listener events

Tags: android, listener

I want my animation to start at the touch and stop at the release of the finger. If the animation finishes its cycle the view becomes invincible.

With my current code, once you hit the button the animation continues even by releasing the finger. The animation finished its cycle without the finger and the view got my invincible.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        init_views();
        init_fonts();
        text.setText("Hello");
        init_clicks();
    }
    private void init_views(){
        round = findViewById(R.id.round);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    private void init_fonts() {
        //Init font
        Raleway_Regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/raleway_regular.ttf");
        Raleway_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/raleway_bold.ttf");
        Roboto_Regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/roboto_regular.ttf");
        Montserrat_Regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/montserrat_regular.ttf");
        PlayFairDisplay_Regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/playfairdisplay_regular.ttf");
        PlayFairDisplay_Italic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/playfair_italic.ttf");
        QuickSand_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/quicksand_light.ttf");
        //txts -> fonts
        text.setTypeface(QuickSand_light);
    }

    private void init_clicks(){
        round.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    // When the user clicks the Button
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        anim();
                        break;

                    // When the user releases the Button
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        round.clearAnimation();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void anim() {

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main2Activity.this, R.anim.anim_btn);


        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
round.setVisibilty(View.INVICBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

        });
        round.startAnimation(anim);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that add double setOnTouchListener :

```
round.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                anim();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
                round.clearAnimation();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    round.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                anim();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
                round.clearAnimation();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```